# CSS header, menu, content and footer position

Tags: css, header, css-position, footer

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #335599;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#footer {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dd1155;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap_content {}

.undef {
  width: 100%;
}

.top_h {
  height: 100px;
}

.bottom_h {
  height: 60px;
}

#page_content {
  padding-left: 150px;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#menu {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #1188FF;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#menu ul li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #992277;
  border-bottom-color: #000000;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  font-family: Cambria;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #167322;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

  <div id="header"></div>

  <div class="undef">
    <div class="top_h"></div>

    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
        <li>Menu item</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="bottom_h"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="page_content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin iaculis nibh id odio laoreet, nec bibendum erat auctor. Vivamus imperdiet nisi eget nisl blandit lobortis. Nam vestibulum scelerisque nisi, sit amet fermentum metus dapibus ut. Etiam et volutpat
        eros, sed porttitor elit. Nulla bibendum ornare metus, in venenatis lectus rhoncus sit amet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce nibh nulla, rhoncus eget laoreet a, aliquam ac libero. Curabitur tristique porttitor congue. Integer lacinia congue
        orci quis vestibulum. Nulla risus nisi, sodales id augue in, laoreet feugiat orci. Vestibulum fermentum sapien est, eget pretium eros adipiscing vel. Nulla malesuada ornare congue. Suspendisse eget enim et dolor porttitor scelerisque ut eu augue.
        Duis vitae risus quis est rutrum consectetur pharetra ullamcorper lacus. Suspendisse vestibulum auctor mi, in laoreet libero pellentesque ut. Donec a elit at ligula viverra dictum vel feugiat elit.
      </p>


      <div class="bottom_h"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>

</div>
```

I want to create a page only by using css that has the following:

1. header height = 100px; must be always on the top of the page(this part is working fine)
2. footer height = 60px; must be always on the bottom of the page (even if the doesn't have enough content. If the page content or the menu have to much content and the browser scroll bar is displayed then the footer still has to be positioned on the bottom).
3. the menu must be in the left of the page and has a width of 150px with elements defined as in the example(this part is also working fine)
4. the page content should extend on the remaining space (it is displayed with black. When all the remaining space is black instead of yellow then it should be ok)

Also the page should dynamically change if the browser window size is changed. The solution should be browser compatible but if it works for firefox or/and chrome then all is ok.

I tried to do this using a lot of tricks but none of them worked. Is it possible to do something like this using only css 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle of my resolution:   http://jsfiddle.net/6rVsE/

2

add to `#footer`:

```
position:fixed; bottom: 0px;
```

3

add to: `#menu`:

```
width: 150px;
```

add to: `#menu ul li`:

```
width: 100%;
```

4

because you are doing relative: I would resolve this in Javascript.  This example is using jQuery.

```
$("#page_content").css("height", $(window).height() - $("#header").height() - $("#footer").height() +"px");
```

Comment: I don't want to use js or jquery to resolve the page_content relative height, because I can't use it. It must be pure css.

Comment: I already tried with the fixed footer but if I have too much content then the footer remains at the bottom of the page but not at the end of the content of the page(I was referring to that end). Thanks anyway for the answer!

Comment: Have you thought to take #page_content and give it,  float:right?

Comment: if you can DEFINE #undef with some sort of defined height it might put you slightly closer.  http://jsfiddle.net/6rVsE/3/ will get you a bit closer.   It changes #menu to float left, and then the height of the #page_content is 100% the page... #undef, and #undef is set to either 100% or some defined height.   If it is set to 100% though, there is an offeset, by the height of the header.

Comment: if i use the calc from css3 I can set then the height of the undef height: calc(100% - 160px);... this will bring me a bit closer but if I have a lot of elements in the menu lets say 30... then if I scroll down then the yellow part of the background starts showing again... which I don't want... I would want the height to be calculated relatively to the hole page with all the content not just what you can see in the window when the page is loaded... (the float:right - I tried it but wouldn't be of much use reason why I used padding-left:150px;

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
#header, #menu, #content, #footer {
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

#header {
  height:100px;
  z-index:9999;
}

#menu {
  width:150px;
  padding:100px 0 60px; /* account for header, footer */
  z-index:9997;
}

#content {
  padding:100px 0 60px 150px; /* account for header, menu, footer */
  z-index:9996;
}

#footer {
  height:60px;
  top:inherit;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:9998;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="menu">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: the fixed approach truncates removes all the additional content of the page. It may look pretty empty but with content added it doesn't look that way. Thanks for your answer!